# Does Kobe Bryant shoot better from far away?

Tags: r, probability, logistic

I am studying how well Kobe Bryant shoots and to do so I have run a logistic regression. The variable shot_made_flag is 0 if missed and 1 if he scored. And I am running the regression against distance from the basket.

```
  logitshots <- glm(df$shot_made_flag ~ df$shot_distance, family = binomial(link="logit"))
Call:  glm(formula = df$shot_made_flag ~ df$shot_distance, family = binomial(link = "logit"))

Coefficients:
 (Intercept)  df$shot_distance  
      0.3681           -0.0441  

Degrees of Freedom: 25696 Total (i.e. Null);  25695 Residual
Null Deviance:      35330 
Residual Deviance: 34290    AIC: 34300
```

As you see the coefficient of distance is negative. So what I do next is to compute the probability of scoring if Bryant is 1 meter farther.

To do so I have done it this way, but I get a positive effect, so I am not sure about it.

```
(exp(coef(logitshots))/(1+exp(coef(logitshots))))
(Intercept) df$shot_distance 
   0.5909933        0.4889768
```

So how would you interpret this? every 1 meter means a 48% more chances of scoring (Lol)? Is this approach the right one? I guess that Kobe scoring from 25 meters is very unlikely (maybe modelling by a quadratic function?)

I'd really appreciate any interesting insight and help! :)

Comment: The relationship is almost surely nonlinear and probably not even one that is simple to approximate with a polynomial.  I suggest a spline model.,

Answer (score 3):

One of your questions is whether the model is appropriate for the data. Without access to the data this is hard to say. A `gam()` instead of a `glm()` as suggested by @PeterFlom in the comments is one natural alternative, though.

As for the interpretation I always recommend to compute some hands-on cases to get a feeling what the non-linear logit curve means. If `shot_distance` is indeed in meters one could consider a range from 0 to 10 meters and then compute the linear predictor (on the logit scale) and then transform it to probabilities:

```
sdist <- 0:10    
linpr <- 0.3681 - 0.0441 * sdist
prob  <- exp(linpr) / (1 + exp(linpr))
prob
## [1] 0.5909998 0.5802988 0.5695217 0.5586784 0.5477788 0.5368332 0.5258519
## [8] 0.5148456 0.5038249 0.4928005 0.4817831
plot(prob ~ sdist, type = "l")
```

[image: prob by sdist]

So you can see that the scoring probability decreases from about 60% to about 50% in this range, i.e., roughly one percentage point per meter. It's been some time that I've been following NBA basketball but this does not seem to be a very plausible model...

Nevertheless, if we accept the model and just want to interpret the coefficients we could check either the *relative* change in the *odds* per meter which are constant:

```
exp(-0.0441)
## [1] 0.9568583
odds <- prob/(1 - prob)
odds[-1]/odds[-11]
## [1] 0.9568583 0.9568583 0.9568583 0.9568583 0.9568583 0.9568583 0.9568583
## [8] 0.9568583 0.9568583 0.9568583
```

Thus, the odds of scoring decrease by about 4.3% per meter.

The *absolute* changes in the *probabilities* are not constant due to the nonlinear logit link. But so close around 50% they are approximately constant and in this case correspond to about 1 percentage point. For example, in comparison to the slope at a distance of 4 meters:

```
-0.0441 * dlogis(0.3681 - 0.0441 * 4)
## [1] -0.01092433
diff(prob)
## [1] -0.01070102 -0.01077706 -0.01084334 -0.01089960 -0.01094562 -0.01098123
## [7] -0.01100629 -0.01102071 -0.01102443 -0.01101743
```